# Line break when combining image_tag and text in Rails navbar

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to combine a logo and the brandname as text in my bootstrap based navbar. The problem is I can't figure out why there is a line break and the text not on the same line as the logo. Can anyone assist?

```
<%= link_to image_tag("brand_logo.png") + " Brandname", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
```

I tried to add "display: inline;" in my CSS-file but this doesn't help. Please see the screenshot for the browser
[inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrEme.png)

Thank you.

Comment: maybe `display: inline-block!important;` =

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the property `display:inline` to the `image_tag` itself.

```
<%= link_to root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' do %>
  <%= image_tag('brand_logo.png', style: 'display:inline') %>
  <%= 'Brandname' %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it!

Answer (score 0):

***Thanks coorasse***

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <%= link_to root_path do %>
      <%= image_tag 'image.svg', alt:'', class:'', style:'display:inline' %>
      <span class="" >TEXT LINK</span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```